# Query data frame in python pandas, can't save query

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of data frames that I'm opening in a for loop. For each data frame I want to query a portion of it and find the average.

This is what I have so far:

```
k = 0
for i in open('list.txt', 'r'):

    k = k+1
    i_name = i.strip()
    df = pd.read_csv(i_name, sep='\t')
    
#Create queries
    A = df.query('location == 1' and '1000 >= start <= 120000000')
    B = df.query('location == 10' and '2000000 >= start <= 60000000')
    print A
    print B
    
#Find average
    avgA = (sum(A['height'])/len(A['height']))
    print avgA
    avgB = (sum(B['height'])/len(B['height']))
    print avgB
```

The problem is I'm not getting the average values I'm expecting (when doing it manually by excel). Printing the query results in the entire data frame being printed so I'm not sure if there's a problem with how I'm querying the data.

Am I correctly assigning the values A and B to the queries? Is there another way to do this that doesn't involve saving every data frame as a csv? I have many queries to create and don't want to save each intermediate query for hundreds of samples as I'm only interested in the average.

Answer (score 4):

This does not do what you expect:

```
    A = df.query('location == 1' and '1000 >= start <= 120000000')
    B = df.query('location == 10' and '2000000 >= start <= 60000000')
```

You are doing the Python "and" of two strings.  Since the first string has a True value, the result of that expression is "1000 >= start <= 120000000".

You want the "and" to be inside the query:

```
    A = df.query('location == 1 and 1000 >= start <= 120000000')
    B = df.query('location == 10 and 2000000 >= start <= 60000000')
```

Secondly, you have the inequality operators backwards.  The first one is only going to get values less than or equal to 1000.  What you really want is:

```
    A = df.query('location == 1 and 1000 <= start <= 120000000')
    B = df.query('location == 10 and 2000000 <= start <= 60000000')
```